# Understanding AutoIT "compilation"

Tags: ollydbg, decompilation, deobfuscation

I'm trying to de-compile a cheat created for my game so I can fix it. The problem is the version used is 3.3.14.2 which no longer has official de-compiler support.

I have tried looking for 3rd party de-compilers but none of them worked for me. I've read somewhere that the `.exe` generated by AutoIT is just an embedded interpreter for AutoIT and the script source code but obfuscated.

Does anyone know how it is compiled so I can use OllyDBG to try and de-obfuscate the script?

Of-course the `.exe` is packed with UPX but can easily be unpacked. So the only problem is script obfuscation. (If my understanding is correct)

I've tried dumping the application memory but didn't find any readable script there. I've also used OllyDBG to run the application but it gave me the error `This is a third-party compiled AutoIt script`. Bit confused why but attaching to the running application works okay.

Comment: wow autoit decompiling faq has a very aggressive stance block block ban ban just for even pronouncing dexxxxxxx. if they are actively preventing  the action then i think your luck is your only hope  ( sorry i havent used autoit just googled why you cant use an old version and read the tidbits )

Comment: You should know that preventing cheats on client side is nearly impossible. everything you can do, they can simply not run, patch out, evade and so on

Comment: @Amirag I’m not trying to prevent cheats from the client side. I’m trying to understand how they are doing it so I can fix it on the server side. To understand it properly I need to see how the cheating prog works.

Answer (score -1):

It may call `IsDebuggerPresent` to check if you're debugging it, so you can't just  create that process by OD, maybe Attach could work. There's another way,
find the condition and set clear `eax` to make it use the other branch.